# Net::SSH::Service::Forward::UNIXServer

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to use the Net::SSH:Gateway gem but without any luck.
I'm executing this:

```
gateway = Net::SSH::Gateway.new(
ssh_host,
user,
:port => ssh_port,
:keys => keys,
:passphrase => passphrase)
port = gateway.open(ssh_host, 3036,3037)
```

But this error pops up:

```
C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.5.2/lib/net/ssh/service/forward.rb:60:in `local': uninitialized constant Net::SSH::Service::Forward::UNIXServer (NameError)
from C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-gateway-1.1.0/lib/net/ssh/gateway.rb:127:in `block in open'
from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
from C:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-gateway-1.1.0/lib/net/ssh/gateway.rb:126:in `open'
from C:/Users/Joker/RubymineProjects/test/asd3.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Has anyone seen this, and can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this repeatedly.  I don't know if this will resolve your problem but I often have to insert:

Net::SSH::Service::Forward::UNIXServer = nil

to even get the script to run.  Let me know if that helps.

Additionally, I would point out that if you are working with MySQL the default port is 3306, I believe, not 3036.

My attempts to connect through a SSH tunnel to MySQL database haven't been successful so I wish you luck.  I may switch to a ODBC/RBI approach